# Cannot run python program as a service in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, zerorpc

I am trying to run a python program as a background service in ubuntu 18.04. It imports zerorpc module which I have already installed with pip3 and tested with python command on terminal. But it shows status: failed when I try to run the program as dummy.service. Below is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Dummy Service
[Service]
Type=Simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/server.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Below is the status of serice after enabling it:

```
dummy.service - Dummy Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dummy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-11-26 16:18:57 IST; 5s ago 

Process: 4101 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/server.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Nov 26 16:18:57 vipul-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Started Dummy Service.

Nov 26 16:18:57 vipul-HP-Notebook python2[4101]: Traceback (most recent call last):

Nov 26 16:18:57 vipul-HP-Notebook python2[4101]:   File "/usr/bin/server.py", line 1, in <module>

Nov 26 16:18:57 vipul-HP-Notebook python2[4101]:     import zerorpc

Nov 26 16:18:57 vipul-HP-Notebook python2[4101]: ImportError: No module named zerorpc

Nov 26 16:18:57 vipul-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: dummy.service: Main process exited, code=exited,      status=1/FAILURE

Nov 26 16:18:57 vipul-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: dummy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I don't know why this is happening. Please help!!

Comment: Your error message does not match your service file (notice what `ExecStart` is). That aside could it be that you have done a pip install of the `zerorpc` package via pip and this is not available when you run it as a service? Maybe you need to ensure all your additional packages are accessible system wide?

Comment: how would I ensure that all packages are available everywhere? I know little about this. I have also changed python2 to python3.

Comment: As already mentioned your ExecStart command is using `python3` but in the logs it shows `python2`. If you have changed the service file you need to reload the systemd manager configuration using `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: I have changed service file accordingly but it still shows same error!

Comment: Did you run `daemon-reload` after changing the service file? You have to run that command in order for systemd to pickup the new command. Afterwards run `sudo systemctl restart dummy`

Comment: If you were to change to a user other than your own (e.g. `su - otheruser`) can you run `/usr/bin/server.py`?

Comment: I have corrected it. This time I installed zerorpc with sudo privileges. As Anon said, package should be available system wide. So installing module with sudo, it makes the module available globally. Thank you all!

Comment: Vipul: I would recommend writing your solution as an answer to this question and then in time you can accept it.

Comment: Please consider upvoting my question as I'm in dire need of it.

Comment: Just want to ask one more thing: If my program running as service expects user input, how would I provide one?

Comment: Vipul: in short - you can't as it's a service and is running unattended. It would be better to alter the program to to read some sort of configuration/data file at start up that contains all it it needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your daemon service is giving error in importing module, the probably you have installed it with pip only. Installing module this way makes it available to a specific user, if you want to make it available globally, you would have to install it with admin privileges like this:

> sudo -H pip3 install module_name